# Is there a Linux Distribution where you can check the validity of downloaded packages?

Tags: software-installation, system-installation

I need a linux distribution where I can download an install image and additional packages and then check their validity (hashes, gpg signatures) offline. The distribution has to run on a Raspberry, btw.

I know Debian quite well and was surprised that this doesn't seem to work there. I found signed installers for alpine, but don't know how to check their validity.

Example: I can go to https://alpinelinux.org/downloads/, download an image and its hash and signature. I'd trust this image.

Then I could go to https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages and download an additional package. How could I trust this package? I see no way to get a hash or a signature..

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you need the distro package manager to do so? If you download a package from an author's website you depend on the author to provide the corresponding hash in the first place

Comment: They are ways to pre-download packages (so that they are checked right after download). But if you don't trust these packages later, why would you trust the key against which they will be checked?

Comment: @xenoid: The pre-download is right what interests me. Can you elaborate on this a bit?

Comment: For debian see the `d`,`--download-only` option of `apt-get`.